# Flutter: Why is my listTile color being overwritten by the container color?

Tags: flutter, listview, colors, flutter-listview, listtile

I have a listTile builder that returns this listTile. The color of the listTile, white, is overwritten by its parent. How do I stop this?

```
return ListTile(
   key: Key(index.toString()),
   tileColor: Colors.white,
   title: Text(widget.userExercises[index].name),
   subtitle: Text("${widget.userExercises[index].reps} Reps"),
   trailing: Text("${widget.userExercises[index].sets} Sets"),
   onTap: () => widget.editFunction(widget.userExercises[index]),
);
```

However, when I run my app, the tileColor is overwritten by the parent Container's color.

```
return Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  color: Colors.lightBlue,
  child: ExerciseTable(
    userExercises: todaysExercises,
    editFunction: _showEditDialog,
  ),
);
```

Resulting in the following:

[image: The tiles with Bench Press should be white]

Thank you! (and sorry for the image size I don't know how to change it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ListTile` paints its `tileColor` on a `Material` widget ancestor. When a colored `Container` is in between the `ListTile` and that ancestor you won't see the `tileColor`. To quote from here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/86355/commits/9341a6b1d0d2852ee3c7eb413bbbdc9327f425c8 :

```
/// Requires one of its ancestors to be a [Material] widget.
/// One ancestor must be a [Material] widget and typically this is
/// provided by the app's [Scaffold]. The [tileColor],
/// [selectedTileColor], [focusColor], and [hoverColor] are not
/// painted by the list tile itself but by the material widget
/// ancestor. This generally has no effect. However, if an opaque
/// widget, like `Container(color: Colors.white)`, is included in
/// between the [ListTile] and its [Material] ancestor, then the
/// opaque widget will obscure the material widget and its background
/// [tileColor], etc. If this a problem, one can wrap a material
/// widget around the list tile, e.g.:
///
/// Container(
///   color: Colors.green,
///   child: Material(
///     child: ListTile(
///       title: const Text('ListTile with red background'),
///       tileColor: Colors.red,
///     ),
///   ),
/// )
```

See also this discussion: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83108

Answer (score 2):

Warp the ListTile with **Material** widget because **tileColor is not painted by the ListTile widget itself** but by the material widget.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised, when I looking at this issue. Wrap the `ListTile` with `Material` will solve the issue, but still I'm not sure how issue is happening.

```
return Material(
 child: ListTile(
   key: Key(index.toString()),
   tileColor: Colors.white,
   title: Text(widget.userExercises[index].name),
   subtitle: Text("${widget.userExercises[index].reps} Reps"),
   trailing: Text("${widget.userExercises[index].sets} Sets"),
   onTap: () => widget.editFunction(widget.userExercises[index]),
 )
);
```